# Why is my Git Extensions Graph totally gray and how can I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, repository, bitbucket, git-extensions

I am using Git Extensions with Visual Studio 2010. My repository is on Bitbucket and I am using SSH and PuTTY to push/pull.

When I open my project and click on browse repository, the first thing I see is a window with a message that starts like this (
Along with two buttons for "Edit .gitignore" and "Commit"):

> There are no commits made to this repository yet.
>
> If this is a normal repository, these steps are recommended:
>   -Make sure you have a proper .gitignore file in your repository
>   -Commit files using commit
>
> If this is a central repository(bare repository without a working
>   dir):
>   -Push changes from another repository

My working directory is set (in a drop down) to a local folder on my computer and the current branch is "master" (also in a drop down).
I can push, pull and commit changes and they will show up in bitbucket but the graph does not show up.

There is another drop down on the right side of the Git Extensions window that has "Branches:" as the label.
If I select "master" from the "Branches:" drop down then I see the graph but everything is gray.

I tried deleting my local repository and re-cloning it from bitbucket and nothing changed.

The graph looks the same as if I were browsing a remote repository... all of the branches and nodes are gray.

Also, I cloned the remote repository as a personal repository... not a central one... and when I first created the remote repository I did it as a central repository.

This does not seem to be a common issue... either that or I did not know what to search for on google.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The video at this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFbCusX9bKs created the repository differently than I originally did..... when I tried it that way it worked..... The difference was that you clone a fresh and empty Bitbucket repo to an empty directory as a personal repo then drop all of your project files into that folder and commmit then push to Bitbucket.......

It could be that my problem was that I created a central repo from an existing project and then pushed it to Bitbucket..... I hope this is useful for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The video at this link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFbCusX9bKs created the repository differently than I originally did..... when I tried it that way it worked..... The difference was that you clone a fresh and empty Bitbucket repo to an empty directory as a personal repo then drop all of your project files into that folder and commmit then push to Bitbucket.......